# How to send a Skype message from the Windows command line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, skype

I would like to send a message to group chat from the Windows command line. I know the chat name from skype, lets say it is 'TestChat'.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: The closest thing I could find is a python API [Skype4Py](http://skype4py.sourceforge.net/doc/html/), but that would require you to install python and write the script yourself.

Comment: This is an awesome question. I would definitely like to know how to do this from a *NIX terminal too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to the Skype4Py comment, I would recommend [Skype4COM](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SEHE.aspx). You'd still need to write the script yourself but there are some examples out there already that show similar things. It's also [officially supported](http://developer.skype.com/accessories) by Skype.

Answer (score 0):

[MsgToSkype.exe](http://www.loriotpro.com/Products/MsgToSkype/CLI_program_for_sending_text_message_to_skype_client_EN.php)
is a command-line program (22k) that can send messages to
another Skype clients using the locally installed & configured Skype client.
It uses the Skype4Com API mentioned by [Matthew Steeples](https://superuser.com/a/328287),
but relieves you from dealing with COM.

It cannot send message to a *group* chat (as described at the above-mentioned page) *"due to limitation of the Skype4Com component. To achieve the same goal* **it is possible** *to use the Category concept of the Skype interface. A Category allows to define a set of users and MsgToSkype can use this Category and browse it to send Instant Message sequentially to all users located in this one."*

However, currently I suspect that this Skype4Com API is [obsolete and will cease to work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18822634) in the near future. But I cannot tell it for sure because it's unclear (for me) how Skype4Com is related to the [Skype Desktop API](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA214/what-is-the-desktop-api), from which message sending capability is going to be removed.