# Send msg on skype with batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch

How can I send messages to my friend on skype with a batch command line?
i've tried, but is used to send images or other media.

> "C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /sendto:XXXXXXX Test

Answer (score 0):

There is no *officially* supported direct method to do this through the command line. Check out the Superuser thread at [How to send a Skype message from the Windows command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/327861/how-to-send-a-skype-message-from-the-windows-command-line).

The thread mentions using the Skype4COM Event Handler, a scriptable interface for Skype, essentially, that works which works with all Skype API messages, including the standard text messages.